# Local storage and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, local-storage

Where are the data stored in local storage? Is it in form of some text or ASCII format or some other? Is it possible to store JSON data in text files (which can be regularly) updated and retrieve them back? I want to store some JSON data but since my requirement is not so big, I want to abstain from using a database for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Local storage *can only store strings* (any data you might have, have to be converted to string upon saving in storage and "revived" upon reading from it).

JSON data is more than fine to be stored as a string so it is good choice of format for keeping complex data in browser storage (either local storage or session storage).

You can learn more about storage here: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

As to *where* the data is being stored, I imagine it varies from browser to browser but you don't have to worry about *where* is the data, since you don't have any direct access to it (only through storage API).

Edit: Quick note - I've found this article stating *where* is storage data stored by Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage (see section "Storage location and clearing the data" at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tiny script to allow storage, and reading of arrays, strings, and objects into local storage.  IT even lets you modify nested keys within the objects you store.  Here is a link to the tiny script. https://github.com/andresgallo/truStorage/blob/master/truStorage.js

Answer (score 0):

Getting:

```
const got = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my-key'));
```

Setting:

```
localStorage.setItem('my-key', JSON.stringify({ a: 'A' }));
```